# Как в java к byte прибавить число?

Tags: java

Есть массив типа байт

`byte mas[] = new byte[10];`

Я хочу изменить значение одного элемента таким образом:

`mas[0] = mas[1] + (byte)1;`

Но получаю ошибку

**error: possible loss of precision 
required: byte
found: int**

Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сумма переменной типа `byte` и константы может превысить `Byte.MAX_VALUE`. Поэтому кастовать нужно всю сумму:

```
mas[0] = (byte)(mas[1] + 1);
```